# Nome não imprimindo

Tags: javascript, html

O que eu queria era receber o nome da pessoa mostra com o alert porém não estou conseguindo

Meu código html

```js
var nome = document.getElementById('id1').value;
function clique(){
  alert(nome);
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="text"/>
<button onclick="clique">Clique aqui</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltava apenas adicionar `()` no `onclick` para chamar a função e colocar a variável dentro do escopo função para que o nome seja capturado durante a execução da mesma.

```js
function clique(){
  var nome = document.getElementById('id1').value;
  alert(nome);
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="text"/>
<button onclick="clique()">Clique aqui</button>
```

Comment: nossa que falta atenção, muito obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Tem dois problemas no seu código:

1) Para chamar uma função `JavaScript` tem que colocar os `()` e de preferência colocar o `;` no final também.

2) Vocês esta pegando o valor do `input` `id1` fora da função, os seja, ele era pego antes de executar a função. Se mantivesse fora o valor impresso no `alert` sempre iria ser vazio.

```js
function clique(){
  var nome = document.getElementById('id1').value;
  alert(nome);
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="text"/>
<button onclick="clique();">Clique aqui</button>
```

Comment: Desculpe se eu for chato, mas por que colocar `;` no final rs?

Comment: O `;` é um delimitador de linha. Se só há 1 linha, não é preciso rs

Comment: @sam, já vi muitos códigos executando vários métodos no mesmo evento, por exemplo `pegaValor();exibeValor();`, por conta disso sempre mantenho `;` para evitar problemas.

Comment: Claro, mas nesse caso não precisa :D